# Appending lines to a file in Node.js causes contents to be written in random order

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, asynchronous

I wrote this code and basically the header line is not always at the first position. It randomly goes to second or third line. Please help--I tried many times.

```
var fs = require('fs');
const path = './Output.csv';

if (fs.existsSync(path)){
  fs.unlinkSync(path);
}

fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(path, 'w'));

fs.appendFile(path,'SamAccountName,Sid \n', function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
});

for (i = 0; i < array_Sid_SidHistory_Full.length; i++) {
  fs.appendFile(path, array_Sid_SidHistory_Full[i]+"\n" , function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Output expected:

```
SamAccountName,Sid 
a,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-8456
b,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-6683
c,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-8459
d,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-3413
e,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-1140
f,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-17241
```

Sometimes it happens that the output comes like this:

```
a,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-8456
b,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-6683
SamAccountName,Sid 
c,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-8459
d,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-3413
e,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-1140
f,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-17241
```

or

```
a,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-8456
SamAccountName,Sid 
b,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-6683 
c,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-8459
d,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-3413
e,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-1140
f,S-1-5-21-541258428-755705122-2342590333-17241
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Node documentation, [`fs.appendFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback) asynchronously appends data to a file. This means that the code has a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) on the file resource, and the arbitrary ordering of the callback execution winds up determining the output (Node dispatches threads under the hood to handle these callbacks).

Ensuring sequential ordering can be done with [`fs.appendFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options). It's common for many Node `fs` functions to have a synchronous version. Alternately, you could await each asynchronous call to resolve before performing the next append, but this seems a bit of a shoehorn in this case.

Assuming the file fits into memory, you can also build the entire string representing the file contents using concatenation, then dump the entire file to disk using one call to `fs.writeFile` (or `fs.appendFile`) and use the callback if necessary to perform further actions.

Answer (score 1):

Using a stream would have the lowest memory footprint:

```
function writeCSV(stream, data) {
    while (data.length > 0) {
        // Process the data backwards assuming the CSV header is the last element.
        // Working backwards and popping the elements off the end allows us to avoid
        // maintaining an index but mutates the original array.
        if (!stream.write(`${data.pop()}\n`)) {
            // Wait for data to drain before writing more.
            stream.once('drain', () => writeCSV(stream, data));
            return;
        }
    }
    stream.end();
}

// Open the write stream and watch for errors and completion.
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
stream.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
stream.on('finish', () => console.log(`Completed writing to: ${path}`));

// Push the header onto the end of the data and write the file.
array_Sid_SidHistory_Full.push('SamAccountName,Sid');
writeCSV(stream, array_Sid_SidHistory_Full);
```

But constructing the file in memory is certainly simpler (described in the answer by @ggorlen):

```
const data = `SamAccountName,Sid\n${array_Sid_SidHistory_Full.join('\n')}\n`;
fs.writeFile(path, data, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
    } else {
        console.log(`Completed writing to: ${path}`)
    }
});
```

Both methods have less overhead that using `fs.appendFile` as the file is only opened and closed once during writing rather than opened and closed for each row of data.